# Are UIViews that are subviews of MTKViews being handled / rendered on the GPU?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, metal, mtkview

I am adding a UIView to a MTKView and animating the UIView in the DRAW delegate method of the MTKViewDelegate.

Will this animation be handled by the GPU / Metal? Should the animation be smoother or the same as if I were using UIView.animate?

```
     func draw(in view: MTKView) {

      let newdescriptor = self.metalview.currentRenderPassDescriptor
      let commandbuffer = self.metalqueue.makeCommandBuffer()
      let commandencoder = commandbuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: newdescriptor!)



      // //////////////////////////// //
      timer += 0.01
      var currenttime = sin(timer)
      uiviewbox.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(sin(timer)))
      // //////////////////////////// //




      commandencoder?.endEncoding()
      let thedrawable = self.metalview.currentDrawable
      commandbuffer?.present(thedrawable!)
      commandbuffer?.commit()
 }
```

Comment: "animating the UIView in the DRAW delegate method of the MTKViewDelegate" What does that mean? Can you show the code, please?

Comment: The draw method gets called every frame and I think is the connection between the iPhone display and GPU. I could definitely be wrong, since shaders I think are the actual functions running on the GPU and the draw method is not a shader. Posting code now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought you meant. :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, and no. In effect, the fact that this view is a subview of the MTKView and that you are using the `draw` method as a clock is completely irrelevant. What you're doing is no different from changing something about the view on every callback from a CADisplayLink — and you would never ask whether *that* was more efficient or on the GPU. In fact, because this is done on the main thread, this is arguably *less* efficient than normal view animation (in the same way as UIKit Dynamics which uses the CADisplayLink technique as well).